# Getstream timeline feed - How do I show threads from single timeline feed?

Tags: getstream-io

I have a timeline feed for a course discussion. The course has many lessons. I would like to display lesson wise thread from this single course timeline feed. I don't want to create timeline feeds for each lessons separately. How is possible from a single timeline feed? Any filtering on the timeline feed can be done to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Generally idea is to have multiple feeds (per course) and have the main timeline feed follows per course feed.

It makes filtering very easy since everything is filtered by feed name.

Having filtering in one feed would cause you additional money because your custom data needs to be indexed.

Comment: We have thousands of courses and may have 100 lessons in each course. So is it a good practice to create feeds for each course and each lessons? Is there any limit for creating timeline feeds? We are currently in the Starter plan.

Comment: There is no practical limit and 100 seems a low number actually.

Comment: Thanks...but It is not 100. 1000 courses (it will be more and more) *100 lessons= 100000 timeline feeds? is that normal?

Comment: Yup. What I meant was that connection links are 100 and you have 1000 copies of it (these copies are cheap). Sounds fine.